# How to set API level for MAUI projects

Tags: .net, .net-core, maui

I am starting with dotnet maui and documentation is very poor at this point.
I have existing project that targets older Android API level and have the Environment ready for this. When I try to build it, I get an error,

```
error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 31. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 31 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change the Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed
```

I couldn't find an option to change API level.

Edit:
I could find a way to target newer versions and added that as an answer, but monikers older than 30 is still not being recognized and I am getting an error,

```
NETSDKZZZZ: Error getting pack version: Pack 'Microsoft.Android.Ref.30' was not present in workload manifests.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest and best solution is to actually install the requested SDK. This speaks of the *target* API level. I think the default for .NET MAUI apps right now is 31.

The minimum required API level to submit apps to the Google Play Store at this point is API level 30.

If you still want to change it, include a node like this in your csproj file:
`<TargetPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">30</TargetPlatformVersion>`

Comment: I had figured out this part and posted same answer.  Will delete mine as the one you posted is more detailed.
Also it seems `31` is the minimum level now.

Comment: I can only select the newest Android Version(33). But i have installed 33, 32, 12, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76299119/how-can-i-select-more-than-android-33-in-the-project-settings-in-a-net-maui-pro

Answer (score 1):

The advice above is to install the missing Android SDK. Rather than googling on how to do that, the best way to do it is to install the desired/missing Android SDK within the Visual Studio 2022 IDE. To do that, access the Tools | Android | Android SDK Manager menu item:

[image]

After that, you'll see a list of possibilities. Sometimes it will be necessary to uncheck/apply then check/apply to re-set your system, but in most cases, you'll just need to check the missing SDK in the list then click Apply Changes to download it.

[image]

Comment: the sdk is installed, but in net7 it only shows 33 instead of 32 and 24 that I have installed (restarted the computer)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to target newer API level:

Setting `TargetPlatformVersion` version in csproj seems to work for newer version (>30).

```
<TargetPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">32</TargetPlatformVersion>
```