# Android Target Framework in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I have a .NET MAUI app targeting .NET 7 and this is what I see in the project file:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

When I open up the properties for my project, I see that the minimum target for Android is set but I don't see anything selected for target API -- see below:
[image]

With these settings, what version of Android API is my app targeting?

I recently received an email from Google Play that has the following statement.

> Now, apps that target API level 29 or below will start experiencing
> reduced distribution starting Jan 31, 2023...

With that said, what API level does my app target if it's targeting `net7.0-android`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If not specified, (presumably - not verified) it will automatically use the highest installed one.
- Click the dropdown triangle. First one is highest. I see `Android 13.0 (API Level 33)`.
- Leaving this blank allows it to update to latest, when VS updates.

Comment: How can i add more Android Versions to VS 22. I have 33, 32, 30 installed. But only 33 is shown at the dropdown box in vs properties

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73032754/199364

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I have installed several Android versions and still only the 33 is displayed

Comment: Ok. Now I've tried that answer, and also can't get it to work. Something must have changed. Create a new question. Then add a comment on Gerald's answer in my link, with a link to your new question. So Gerald will see that there is some problem.

Answer (score 1):

The google's official document said:

> Starting in January 2023, app updates must target Android 12 or higher and adjust for behavioral changes in Android 12; except for Wear OS apps, which must target Android 11 or higher.

So I suggest you set your project's Android Target Framework as Android 12.0(Api 31). It meets google's requirement and needn't to do the job about fitting the android 13.0.

For more information, you can check the official document about [Meeting Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk).