# How can i select more than Android 33 in the project settings in a .NET MAUI project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

how can I view and select all installed versions in Android target settings in a .NET MAUI project? I have multiple versions installed but can only select the 33.

[image: Android Targets Settings]

Comment: You should only use this setting if you want to target a specific version only. If you want to target all Android versions, you should instead just add the `net7.0-android` target to the `<TargetFrameworks>` property in the *.csproj* file. What is the reason that you want to change this?

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know this. Then everything is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Julian suggested, you will only need use this **Target Android Setting** setting on condition that you want to target a specific or particular version(e.g. `Android 13.0`).

If you want to target all Android versions, you should add the `net7.0-android`  in your .csproj file like below:

```
<TargetFrameworks> net7.0-android;</TargetFrameworks>
```